# Attempting to install SQL Server 2008 somewhere other than the C:\ drive

Tags: windows, ssms

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 Management Studio on a Microsoft Windows Server 2003 machine, however I do not have enough space on the C:\ partition, so I'd like to install it on the D:\ partition.  When I go through the installation, the install path is grayed-out.  Some people have said that you have to uninstall any previous versions of SQL Server, which I did but to no avail.  Anyone have any suggestions on how to get Management Studio installed on a different partition or how to edit this seemingly read-only field during the installation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you uninstalled the previous versions, did you clear the registry entries? Those could keep you from changing the installation directory.